# Binding Event on the Pagination of Table

Tags: angular, angular5, ng2-smart-table

I am using this package https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table

The data is loaded from the server using the API, I have around 100k records to be shown in the database, that's why I need to dynamically load the data from the server based upon the page. that's why I need to bind an event to the pagination's each button so that I can get the particular records from the database.

Looking forward to hearing your suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn some details about the expected format of questions on the site. As it is, this question is asking for a solution. The expectation of most questions on Stack Overflow is you have made some effort into a solution and have run into an issue, with your question being about the specific issue. Please attempt to solve this problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: @Vikas, I have actually tried to solve it. But I am unable to bind the event with the pagination.

Comment: ain't you missing this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/24

Comment: @AliSajid, you can use the Angular Material Tables instead of this. as I have faced the same issue and didnt found any other solution